# Can't change terminal window size in C# Console

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, console-application

I'm trying to use Console.SetWindowSize() to change the window size of the Console, for a C# Console application. In previous versions of Visual Studio or Windows, this would work. Now it does not.

Steps to reproduce:

1. In Windows 11, Visual Studio 2019, create a new C# Console App (.NET Framework) application
2. Add the code to the main function:

```cs
Console.SetWindowSize(10, 10);
Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
Console.ReadLine();
```

3. Run the code. I get the following result.

[image]

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75529443/console-setwindowsize-and-console-clear-not-working-as-expected) which suggests changing the terminal output mode. I tried setting the terminal output using Enviroment > Terminal from the settings search bar in Visual Studio 2019, to either Developer Command Prompt or Ubuntu WSL terminals, but neither allowed resizing the Console window.

[image]

Is there a solution?

Comment: try changing the default terminal app - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-is-now-the-default-in-windows-11/ to the old cmd instead the new terminal app

Comment: currently on a PC and I could test my previous comment and it seems to work on my side, did it help you?

Comment: found an open issue to support it on the new terminal app: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5094

Comment: Thanks @RandRandom, I posted this at the end of the day and haven't had the opportunity to test. Will update this question once I've tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please adjust the following settings

[image]

The following is the console output

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WindowHeight = 20;
        Console.WindowWidth = 20;
        Console.WriteLine("Test 1");
        Console.WriteLine("Max height: " + Console.LargestWindowHeight.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Max width: " + Console.LargestWindowWidth.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
        Console.SetWindowSize(10, 10);
        Console.WriteLine("Test 2");
        Console.WriteLine("Max height: " + Console.LargestWindowHeight.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Max width: " + Console.LargestWindowWidth.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
    }
```

[image]